# Randomise the endpoints of parallel curve lines (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, random, lines

I'm looking for a solution how I can switch start and endpoints of parallel curve lines randomly with Geometry Nodes.

What I have so far is this:
[image]

10 parallel curve lines, divided into 10 segments by resampling it.

Now I want to somehow reassemble the start and endpoint of the lines. Imagine 10 cables plugged into a router and than randomly switch the cable into another slot.

It should look like this:
[image]

a) is what I have so far, b) would be simple but fine, c) would be great, to have 2 offsets in order to define where the switch should happen.

Any (simple) solution? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of geonodes [sorting] options to randomly sort the available coordinates:

[image]

You can adjust *Set Position: Offset* to make the crossing more readable:

[image]

Comment: Wow that was fast, thank you so much Markus! That's exactly what I was looking for, even with an offset, great work!